# VBA Delivery Receipt Requested Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to make a `.DeliveryReceiptRequested = True` instead of `.ReadReceiptRequested = True` when sending an outlook mail through excel but it's not working and I'm not getting any errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more context: how is it not working? are you getting errors? (you'll need to post more code). Is the functionality not working as expected? (what's the actual vs expected?)

Comment: @paulbica no errors. It just nothing happens. If I replaced it with `.ReadReceiptRequested = True` it works. But I don't want the `Delivery ` one not the `Read` one

Comment: Try `.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True`

Comment: @TimWilliams could you please post this as an answer to accept it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
```